Using Pgn extract through command prompt
I have one pgn file with merged variation and I would like to use pgn extract to make many pgn files splitting all the variations within the pgn files as games. The command that I am using in the folder where pgn extract is put is as follows: pgn-extract -#2 --splitvariants 3.pgn
The file 2.pgn is the main file and I want the variations to be put in the 3.pgn file but its not happening. I managed to make it work and was happy but after many days I am not able to do the same. The command prompt shows: Processing stdin     and things are not happening.

The basic usage of --splitvariants is:
pgn-extract --splitvariants inputfile.pgn --output outputfile.pgn

Given the files you have named, you should use:
pgn-extract --splitvariants 2.pgn --output 3.pgn

